# How to Integrate VC++ project in VC# project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

In VC++ we can use header files, but in VC# it's not possible. Is there any way to use the header file (.h file) in C#? I have defined some structures and `#defines` in .h file.

How can I use all those structures & enums in a C# project and is it possible to integrate the C++ code in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET does not exist headers because all needed metadata is contained itself in referenced assembly.

And yes,  you can integrate C++/C code by using a C++/CLI module. C++/CLI can do managed and unmanaged code together in an assembly. The C# can then use the C++ assembly almost as if it is C# code

Comment: Hi can u tell me how to integrate the C++ module in C# project? @soreigon

Comment: This tutorial sould be enough to understand how to use C++/CLI module. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42319/Using-NET-Classes-Modules-from-Native-C